# is it possible to get CPU usage for particular MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql, monitoring

is  it possible to get CPU  usage for particular MYSQL query?

Comment: [SHOW PROFILE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-profile.html)

Comment: @Akina i want to get CPU usage for particular  mysql query  like stored procedure..  in mysql so any idea please for that?

Comment: The _elapsed_ time for a `CALL` is easy to get via any client.  The _CPU_ time is not available.  The elapsed time for the statements _inside_ is not easy, but possible.  Which do you need?  When optimizing SQL, elapsed tends to be a better metric than CPU.

Comment: @kkkk Yes, View ALL of the URL posted by Akina.  Near the end you will see CPU.

Comment: @WilsonHauck   thank you very much i solved  my problem

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution @Akina